# Unable to view Laravel default page from browser

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, loading, default

Want to view laravel default page from browser. OR, couldn't connect from local machine to Laravel which is installed on virtual machine.

I have installed Ubuntu to my virtual box. Than also have successfully install laravel to Ubuntu (NGINX + MySQL + PHP 7.2 + Laravel). But, I am not able to see laravel default page from browser.
I have tried putting virtual machine IP in browser (x.x.x.x:8000). It says "connection refused". But web server (NGINX) default pages loads without a problem.

I want to be able to start laravel project in present setting. ( In a local machine, a virtual machine is installed. In virtual machine Ubuntu is installed. In Ubuntu, Web server and laravel all are installed). The result must be seen from local machine (browser). I'm using windows 10 as Host machine.
I'm using windows 10 as a Host machine.

Comment: First try to see if you can reach the website from the local machine. If so, report back here.

Answer (score 0):

nginx runs on port 80 by default so accessing x.x.x.x:8000 will not actually try to access any nginx hosted websites

Running x.x.x.x:8000 tries to connect to the development server typically started using `php artisan serve` however the default configuration for this command is to bind to the localhost and would therefore not be accessible from the outside world.

You can instead try running:

```
php artisan serve --host=x.x.x.x
```

where x.x.x.x is the IP of your virtual machine according to the host machine

Alternatively you should setup nginx to serve your website via a virtual host. Refer to [the manual of nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) on how to do this